# Logs to ElasticsSearch using kinesisstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, fluentd

I am trying to understand the Kinesis data streams and I am getting little confused with the terminology and how the big picture looks like.
So, I am running a service on a server, EKS cluster, and want to send the logs to ElasticSearch. The current setup is I am using fluentD on EKS nodes to collect logs and ship them to kinesis stream which then reports to ElasticSeach where they can be analyzed using kibana.

But,

I am not sure what is happening with the kinsesis streams. When fluentD is sending the log data, according to https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/faqs/ there will be a partition key and sequence number associated with the blob of data. Now, I am unable to understand a few things:

1. Who, from the producer side, is creating the partition key, and how?
2. What is the role of the index? Is the index something like data and shards being log data for that particular date?
3. Since there are sequencing associated based on the partition keys, how do we see the logs in kibana in a sequential manner? This would mean the partition keys are also somewhat sequential.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are doing is the ELK Stack and in my opinion, your flow is missing the Logstash lead to missing some feature of the stack.

1. In https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html:

"A data record is the unit of data stored in a Kinesis data stream. Data records are composed of a sequence number, a partition key, and a data blob, which is an immutable sequence of bytes. Kinesis Data Streams does not inspect, interpret, or change the data in the blob in any way. A data blob can be up to 1 MB." So they are auto-generated by Kinesis to queue your logs, so that the Elasticsearch instances won't be crashed.

2. I'm confused with it too. But you can imagine that it is like the name you created of the logs you are pushing to Cloudwatch. You need Logstash to seperate logs to multiple indexs so that you can know which are you looking for.
3. Kibana is listing the logs in index by timestamp in default.

I'm doing the ELK Stack for 1 weeks so I can't make sure that what I am talking here is completely right. Please correct me if I was wrong